# multiple select only giving first selection when sending to firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

my multi-select selection is only giving the output as my first selection. I'm sending the data to firebase, and only the first selection is reflected there. For example, if I select (energy, health care, real estate) in my firebase it only shows energy.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="Sector" value="sector" id="interested_sector" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" data-live-search="true">
   <option value="">Sector</option>
   <option value="energy">Energy</option>
   <option value="materials">Materials</option>
   <option value="consumer discretionary">Consumer Discretionary</option>
   <option value="consumer staples">Consumer staples</option>
   <option value="health care">Health Care</option>
   <option value="financials">Financials</option>
   <option value="information technology">Information Technology</option>
   <option value="telecommunication services">Telecommunication services</option>
   <option value="utilites">Utilites</option>
   <option value="real estate">Real Estate</option>
</select>
```

Here's is the snippet of code in my .js file that sends data to realtime database

```
var interested_sector = getInputVal('interested_sector')

 function getInputVal(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

function saveUserInfo( interested_sector){
    firebase.database().ref('User_info/'+id).update({
        interested_sector: interested_sector,
    }).then(() => {
      window.location = //it goes to a different html page;
    })
}
```

Comment: console log(interested_sector) please! so that we can see what values are you getting back, which you are sending for the update

Comment: hey I have added the answer that will get you what you are looking for, read the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A firebase RealTime Database is made up of JSON Objects, when you get the Values from the input, make sure they return in proper format, here, you seem to be updating an existing key that is called `interested_sector` and adding value `health, energy etc` to it. As Realtime Database accepts JSON, what you send has to be a proper JSON, that is where your code is breaking the value and probably taking the first number, you need to run through all the values taken in and decide in what format do you want to store them?

for example:

```
{
   interested_sector: {
                         1: 'health',
                         2: 'energy'
                      }
}
```

or

```
{
   interested_sector: "health, energy"
}
```

as you can see both are working options, but you need to parse the values first before you send them for an update.

So after testing your code, it turns out that `interested_sector` value changes everything you select a new value, it replaces the old value, that is why when you update the field in firebase database, it only shows the latest of the values,

so for example:
if you select 'Energy' and hit the button to save info, it will save 'Energy'

and then you click on 'Materials' and hit the button to save the info, the `interested_sector` value gets changed and replaces the old value and the function to save the info changes the firebase value as well.

solution is to add a local var that keeps the value and keeps on appending them interested_sector += new value and use a separator like ',' or ';'.

so the correct code of the above, should be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select name="Sector" value="sector" id="interested_sector" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="sector">Sector</option>
    <option value="energy">Energy</option>
    <option value="materials">Materials</option>
    <option value="consumer discretionary">Consumer Discretionary</option>
    <option value="consumer staples">Consumer staples</option>
    <option value="health care">Health Care</option>
    <option value="financials">Financials</option>
    <option value="information technology">Information Technology</option>
    <option value="telecommunication services">Telecommunication services</option>
    <option value="utilites">Utilites</option>
    <option value="real estate">Real Estate</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="getCalled()">Get Called</button>
  <script>
    var final_val = "";

    function getInputVal(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }

    function getCalled() {
      var interested_sector = getInputVal('interested_sector');
      final_val += interested_sector + ', ';
      console.log(final_val);
      alert(final_val);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

FYI: firebase's update function doesn't append to the old value, it changes only the specific fields that you want to change and keeps all the other fields the same. unlike ref().set() function which completely rewrites the entire json object

Comment: Could you please explain how to parse this, I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: @RoobeshBalaji sure, tell me the console.log of the interested_sector, the var

Comment: @RoobeshBalaji okay I am going to run this code locally and see the result